# Issue with fancybox2 - $.fancybox.resize is not a function - error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Javascript

```
/*Corner by Arthur Wulf White
jquery,  jquery ui and jeditable required
*/
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a.magicInput").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ol.addItems").append('<li>Something</li>');
        $.fancybox.resize();
    });
    $("a.fancy").fancybox(       
    {
        'scrolling' : 'no',
        'autoScale' : true,
        'autoDimensions' : true

    });
    return false;
});
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>
            studyWise - Log in
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancy/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancy.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancy/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />    

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
<div id="menu">
    <a class="fancy" href="#fancybox">Open</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="secret">
        <div id="fancybox">
            <a class="magicInput" href="">Ok</a>
            <ol class="addItems">

            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Result:

```
$.fancybox.resize is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$.fancybox.resize();

fancy.js (line 9)
$.fancybox.resize is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$.fancybox.resize();

fancy.js (line 9)
$.fancybox.resize is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$.fancybox.resize();

fancy.js (line 9)
$.fancybox.resize is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$.fancybox.resize();
```

All I want is a working example where the fancybox extends/ stretches to fit the whole list inside it. Thanks - it should only be one or two more lines in jsfiddle, please help cause I have no idea why it is not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using fancybox **v2.x**. Options for this version are new and not compatible with previous versions (1.3.x).

`$.fancybox.resize()` **is NOT** a valid method for fancybox v2.x, use `$.fancybox.update()` instead. It is the same case for `autoScale` and `autoDimensions`, which are options for v1.3.x

Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the right set of options for the version you are using.

Answer (score -2):

[How do you resize Fancybox at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994876/jquery-fancybox-resize)

[FancyBox resize width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398420/fancybox-resize-width)

I guess that would help you. From these errors its clearly depicting that there is any JS file missing.

Comment: You are unfortunately wrong, it just does not exist in this version

Comment: My bad I haven't noticed that.